# Gendre ou beau-fils

Tags: usage, histoire

Peut-on m'expliquer la raison pour laquelle on dit "gendre" au lieu de "beau-fils?"  Après tout, on dit "beau-père" et "beau-frère."

Comment: Ta question s'étend également à « belle-fille » et « bru ». C'est moins utilisé, mais tout de même encore quelques fois mentionné.

Answer (score 14):

Selon le Petit Robert :

> *Gendre*. Le mari d'une femme par rapport au père et à la mère de celle-ci.
>
> *Beau-fils*. Pour un conjoint, Fils que l'autre conjoint a eu précédemment.

Un gendre est donc le mari de son propre enfant et un beau-fils est le fils d'un nouveau conjoint (ou conjointe) issu d'une union précédente.

Pour ce qui est de beau-père, il s'emploie désormais et pour le nouveau conjoint d'un parent et pour le père de son conjoint. Cependant, il y eu un temps où il y avait un mot pour chaque situation. Un beau-père était le père de son conjoint, et on appelait un « parâtre » le nouveau conjoint de sa mère (et son féminin « marâtre »).

On utilise encore beau-frère et demi-frère pour distinguer les liens entre les personnes.

Comment: Ok pour la théorie, mais en pratique, je n'entends plus jamais personne parler de gendre.

Comment: C'est bizarre, moi c'est le contraire au Québec. Gendre est très utilisé et je n'entends presque pas beau-fils, mais je ne connais pas beaucoup de familles reconstituées qui pourraient utiliser beau-fils de cette façon.

Comment: Chez moi, j'entends les deux dans les sens donnés par la réponse. Par contre je n'entends que beau-père, belle-mère et belle-fille et pas leurs pendants qui sonnent vieillis ou péjoratifs.